# Save data in database in php

Tags: javascript, php, sql, html

I have built two pop up divs in my webpage. Initially the first div - `div1`- is loaded which contains drop down menus. This `div1` contains a button `Next` which will close the first div and open the new div; `div2`. `Div2` contains `input` fields where the user will enter the name, email address, phone number etc and click on the button `submit`. The `submit` button call on the php code that connects to the `sql` database and saves the data in `div2` to the database:

```
/* Specify the server and connection string attributes. */
$serverName = "xxx-PC\SQLExpress";
$connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"Salesforce");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
if($conn === false)
{
      die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
else 
{
/*Insert data.*/
$insertSql = "Insert into Salesforce.dbo.customer_details (Name, Company, Email, Phone, Assets, Comm, Capability)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
* Construct the parameter array. */
$params1 = array($from_fullname ,
               $email_message,
               $from_email,
               $Phone,
               'vehicles',
               'xyz',
               'abc');
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $insertSql, $params1);
if($stmt === false)
{
/*Die if other errors occurred.*/
die('Errors: ' . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), TRUE));
}
else
{
echo '<br clear="all"><label style="color:red;">Thank you for your details.</label>';
}
```

I tried to get the data from the drop down in `div1` through the following code but it didnt work:

```
$assets = trim(strip_tags($_POST['track']));
```

where `track` is:

```
<select id="track" name="track" style="background-color: #ffffff;" onchange="selection(this)">
        <option value="personnel">Personnel</option>
        <option value="vehicles">Vehicles</option>
        <option value="personnelVehicles">Personnel & Vehicles</option>
        <option value="maritime">Maritime</option>
        <option value="aircraft">Aircraft</option>
        <option value="all">All of the above</option>
</select>
```

How can I fetch data from the dropdowns from `div1` and pass it to the php script when `submit` is clicked from `div2`?

EDIT1: The `submit` button calls on the javascript where div2 fields are checked. In here, I can pick the value of the dropdown of `div1` through the following:

```
var assets = $("#track :selected").text(); //the text content of the selected option
```

Can I pass this variable from the javascript to the php file where I need to make call to the `SQL` connection?

Comment: What is the code for `selection()`? Also is `div1` and `div2` under the same `<form>`?

Comment: No both divs are not under the same form. Infact both are only divs and not under a `<form>` at all.

Comment: @Sarah then rewrite submit using javascript or place them in the same `<form>`

Comment: A `<form>` tag is necessary for your `$_POST` variables to recognize your **inputs**. If you do not want to use a `<form>` tag, you would need to use `AJAX` which has it's own other uses but you probably don't have the necessity to use `AJAX`, so I recommend you to place your `div`'s between the `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions to store the data and retrieve it as and when needed

For Ex:

```
if(isset($_POST['div2']))
{
//use session variables
$div1_data=$_SESSION['xyx'];
//And then can insert using prepared statements
}
```

**NOTE:** Since you are saying that these two divs are not in a form, you can use a jquery AJAX method to send the datas asynchronously to tht php page which performs the insert option

Comment: You mean I store this data in the session when the `next` button is clicked in `div1`? How can this be done?

Comment: add session_start(); function at the start of the script. and then you can use the $_SESSION global variables to store the datas in a persistent way. Lot more info here  http://in2.php.net/session_start

Comment: I tried to pick the drop down data selection through `$assets    = $_SESSION['track'];` but it doesnt work. Any tips?

Comment: Your <select> tag is wrong, It should be like this:              <select id="track" name="track[]" style="background-color: #ffffff;" onchange="selection(this)">                                         NOTE: Have a look at the "name" attribute, name="track[]"

Comment: I dont know why you are not including this popup into a form tag.Action attr of the tag will be the php page.It will save you a lot of headache.Seriously!!